# Why does this code display 'A' on start without any input?

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

This is a morse code translator for microbit but it displays 'A' on start

```
from microbit import *
morse={'.-': 'A', '-...': 'B', '-.-.': 'C', '-..': 'D', '.': 'E', '..-.': 'F', '--.': 'G', '....': 'H', '..': 'I', '.---': 'J', '-.-': 'K', '.-..': 'L', '--': 'M', '-.': 'N', '---': 'O', '.--.': 'P', '--.-': 'Q', '.-.': 'R', '...': 'S', '-': 'T', '..-': 'U', '...-': 'V', '.--': 'W', '-..-': 'X', '-.--': 'Y', '--..': 'Z', '.----': '1', '..---': '2', '...--': '3', '....-': '4', '.....': '5', '-....': '6', '--...': '7', '---..': '8', '----.': '9', '-----': '0', '--..--': ', ', '.-.-.-': '.', '..--..': '?', '-..-.': '/', '-....-': '-', '-.--.': '(', '-.--.-': ')'}

message=''
while True:
    morseChr=''
    if button_a.is_pressed:
        morseChr+='.'
    if button_b.is_pressed:
        morseChr+='-'
    if button_a.is_pressed and button_b.is_pressed:
        message+=morse[morseChr]
        display.show(message)
        sleep(1000*len(message))
        display.clear()
```

I expect it to translate the button presses into a message but it just shows 'A'

Comment: If this is a long term project you may want to consider storing your Morse dictionary in an external file as it might save you a headache or two in the future.

Comment: I don't see why this question is being up voted. It's a simple and obvious bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your current logic:

First, whenever you press A and B simultaneously, `.-` will be added to your message. To avoid that, use an `else if` and move the A and B case first (because that should be higher priority than just A or B).

Secondly, you can actually never add any other character to your message than an A, because your `morseChar` is reset to an empty string in each loop. You would need to move the variable outside of the loop to keep track of the previous input.

Further, is_pressed is a function according to the microbit documentation.

The resulting code would look like this:

```
message=''
morseChr=''

while True:
    if button_a.is_pressed() and button_b.is_pressed():

        # First check if the entered char is actually valid
        if morseChr not in morse:
            morseChr='' # reset chars to avoid being stuck here endlessly
            # maybe also give feedback to the user that the morse code was invalid
            continue

        # add the char to the message
        message += morse[morseChr]
        morseChr=''

        display.show(message)
        sleep(1000*len(message))
        display.clear()

    elif button_a.is_pressed():
        morseChr+='.'

    elif button_b.is_pressed():
        morseChr+='-'
```